# remove character on database

Tags: javascript, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to submit longtext value with laravel and JS.I've tried to create a text value who is send to my phpmyadmin but when i store my text backslash appear in my text.

```
    var text;
var val;
  text = " { \"case\" : { \"";

for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
    val = document.getElementById("case"+ index).value
    if(index == 99){
    text+= `${index}`+"\""+" : \""+ `${val}` +"\"  "
    }
    else{
    text+= `${index}`+"\""+" : \""+`${val}`+"\" , "
    }
}
text+= "}}"
```

console output: `{ "case" : { "0" : "0" , 1" : "0" , 2" : "0" , 3" : "0" , 4" : "0" , 5" : "0" , 6" : "0" , 7" : "0" , 8" : "0" ...`

database storage `"{ \"case\" : { \"0\" : \"0\" , 1\" : \"0\" , 2\" : \"0\" , 3\" : \"0\" , 4\" : \"0\" , 5\" : \"0\" , 6\" : \"0\" , 7\" : \"0\" , 8\" : \"0\" ..."`

Comment: There seem to be missing quotes in your output. Are you trying to create JSON?

Comment: Try using single quotes instead. For example: `'"'` (which is `[single quote][double quote][single quote]`)

Comment: yeah, i want to store json in my database.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript understands the / but your database won't,You can try to remove the slashes from the text before inserting into the database.You can try this before inserting

```js
 var x="{ \"case\" : { \"0\" : \"0\" , 1\" : \"0\" , 2\" : \"0\" , 3\" : \"0\" , 4\" : \"0\" , 5\" : \"0\" , 6\" : \"0\" , 7\" : \"0\" , 8\" : \"0\" ..."
 x.replace(" \"","naveen")
 console.log(x)
```

Comment: in fact my text variable dont have backslash so in can't remove them with replace function.

Comment: yes, i've tried this but even if i try to store a single string like "test" with double quotes, the database put backslash on my table (i need to store double quote to make json on my db)

Comment: Could it be a database problem instead of a javascript problem?